# Animal gene in plants

Tags: genetics, gene-expression, gene

Usually only microbes, specifically bacteria are used to express genes of other species for various functions. But, it is possible to try and express an animal gene into a plant. Bacteria like [*Bacillus thuringiensis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacillus_thuringiensis) is used in many plants like cotton, to modify them to BT cotton with insecticidal properties. Can one use an animal gene to get those characteristics in the plant?

Comment: What kinds of characteristics you are looking for ? I mean you can express successfully lot of animal proteins, pharmaceuticals and antigens into plant ([Julian KC 2003](http://www.nature.com/nrg/journal/v4/n10/full/nrg1177.html)). But I don't think they are any way important to plants.

Answer (score 1):

One example that I am aware of where an animal transgene was put into a plant was to produce the ZMapp, a chimeric, monoclonal antibody against the Ebola virus.

This is a wikipedia article on [ZMapp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMapp), that gives you an idea of the process.

Other than this, I am not all that familiar with plant transgenics, other than Round Up resistance genes that were transfected from soil bacteria that developed a resistance to the active chemical in Round Up.

Hopefully other answers can provide you with more details, but these are the two examples that I know off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago plant scientists introduced a protein (afa3)in tomato from Winter Flounder, a type of fish surviving freezing conditions. The idea was to make a frost resistant tomato but I believe they did not have much success. Anti-GMO activists had a field day however with baseless claims of making tomato's smell like fish and other nonesense.

Comment: I was looking at adding a particular gene of the penguin that makes its skin thick to survive the winter, in a cotton plant. Do you think that could work?

Comment: I don't know much about pinguin skin but I know it is very very different compared to plant epidermis. It seems rather unlikely but it all depends on the gene